# Excel defining range across 100+ sheet tabs, remove duplicates in column for 100+ Sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Use case: I want to copy data from column A to Column B (where column A, B are arbitrary columns). Once the data is in Column B, I want to remove duplicate entries within column B.

Make a loop that moves data from column A to column B and then removes duplicates for each sheet in a workbook.

```
`Sub Copy()
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Range("A1:A100")
        Destination:=Worksheets(i).Range("B1")
    Next
End Sub
`
```

For testing I separated the tasks into two different Sub(). `Sub Copy()` is working and correctly copies my data. Sheet1 is also named "Sheet1" for my specific workbook

```
`Sub RemoveStuff()
    Dim rng As Range
    For j = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Range("B1"),Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Select
        rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(1), Header:=xlGuess
    Next
End Sub
`
```

My error seems to be in defining the range correctly. Each sheet will have a different number of entries to remove duplicates from. Sheet1 might have 50 rows and reduce to 6. Sheet2 could have 70 and reduce to 3. Sheet3 could have 20 rows and reduce to 12 uniques. Excel does not let you remove duplicates from range (B:B!)

How can I properly define my range so I can remove duplicates in a loop for a dynamically defined range for each sheet(sheet=tabs in workbook)?

EDIT 2-23-17
New code from Y0wE3K

`Sub RemoveStuff()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Columns("P:P").RemoveDuplicates,Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    Next
 End Sub`

*Still does not work. If I manually select Column P before I run the macro, it works. But it only goes for the one sheet I have selected, it does not seem to execute the loop. Definitely does not automatically do each sheet, or prompt me for each one.* 
EDIT: 3/4

Make sure that you do not have any protected data, I also experienced issues with pivot tables but I think this may be permissions thank you for help.

Comment: Remove the `.Select` from `Set rng = .... .Select`

Comment: Your `RemoveStuff` loop won't actually change anything each loop.  Do you mean to select all the sheets and set a range there? You also should be careful, and add the worksheet before both `Range("B1")` in there.  Otherwise the range grabbed will just be that of the ActiveSheet.

Comment: Are you sure that `Copy` is working ?!?!?!

Comment: Further to @YowE3K s answer below, the copy sub is missing the `.copy`

Comment: @VBAPete ... and the line continuation character.

Comment: Yes copy is working. Sorry I had some formatting issues and must have missed that line. I have .copy after the range A in sub copy

Comment: `Worksheets(i).Range("A1:A100").Copy_
        destination:=Worksheets(i).Range("B1")`

Comment: @BruceWayne can you please fill me in? That is what happened after I made the edits. My copy sub is working now. My remove stuff sub is only looking in whatever the active range is. Even though I am saying P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `RemoveStuff` subroutine can be rewritten as:

```
Sub RemoveStuff()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets ' Use Worksheets instead of Sheets, 
                              ' in case there are any Charts
        'You can just select the whole column, rather than selecting
        'specific rows
        ws.Columns("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlGuess
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: this does not work. My new code is this:

`Sub RemoveStuff()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
         ws.Columns("P:P").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    Next
End Sub
`

see edits

Comment: @ktgold I'm afraid I can think of no reason why that code shouldn't work.  (The code you pasted into your question won't, because of the extra `,` in it.)  I tested it, and it happily removed duplicates in the three worksheets that my test workbook contained.

Comment: My mistake, after searching through each sheet I realized there was a sheet with protected data that was breaking it. I fixed and it worked fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub RemoveStuff()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ws.Columns("P:P").RemoveDuplicates,Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    Next
 End Sub
```

This code will work. As a final note, please make sure you have no Protected Data, or pivot tables inside of the sheets you need to run the remove script on. For whatever reason that caused mine to fail, but running my script on the correct sheets that are unprotected worked GREAT.